# Ruby loop local variables and inmutability

Tags: ruby, functional-programming

I have the following code:

```
# Assuming each element in foo is an array.
foo.each do |bar|
  zaz = bar.first
  # Other code using zaz, but not modifying it.
end
```

Will `zaz` local variable be modified on each iteration inside this loop, making it mutable? I am not sure about the behavior of Ruby here.

Comment: My bad, I meant zaz variable not foo. I already edited the question.

Comment: _"making this code mutable"_ – what do you mean? `Array#first` doesn't modify the array and `zaz` is never used.

Comment: I didn't post the question correctly, now I fixed it. Just wanted to know if `zaz` would be considered inmutable. In my real code `zaz` is referenced but never modified.

Comment: after iteration, zaz üill be equal to the first element of the last array in foo multidimensional array.

Comment: So in the next iteration, zaz value will be modified or will be a different instance?

Comment: @Navarro "mutable" and "immutable" usually refers to objects. Variables are supposed to change, as the name implies. So the answer is yes or no, depending of what `zaz` means: the variable `zaz` does change, but the object `zaz` is referring to does not change.

Comment: The do ... end block will be executed for each element of foo. So zaz variable will be a new variable for each block execution. It will never overwrite the variable from the step before. It's not possible. If you define zaz before the each statement, than it will be changed by each block execution.

Comment: @Stefan Talking about mutable vs. immutable variables is perfectly common and in the context of function programming (which this question is tagged with) I'd definitely disagree with "Variables are supposed to change".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`each` loops often mutate the object. Each has to do something.
Because `each` doesn't return anything useful - it returns the array itself, It won't mutate the object if it sends every element somewhere, like to be printed on screen.

```
foo.each do |bar|
  # do something with element like
  # print it, change it, save it
end
```

Functional alterantive is map

```
foo.map { |bar| bar.something }
```

It returns new array which is original array processed in immutable way. Obviously you have to be careful to use immutable methods. This would not be immutable:

```
foo.map { |bar| bar.something! }
```

Here `something!` does something destructive to the element of array.
However I have never seen `map` used like that. Use `each` for something destructive.

Comment: _"Every each loop is destructive"_ – can you explain that?

Comment: `each` evaluates the block but ignores its value. Also, `each` simply returns its receiver unchanged. The only possible way in which `each` is not simply a no-op is if the block has a side-effect. Just look at the myriad of questions on SO about "why does my `ary.each do |i| i+1 end` not do anything?"

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Comment: _"Most each loops mutate the object"_ – that's a bold claim :-)

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the code before the loop, really.

If that is *all* the code, then `zaz` is a block-local variable, and a *new* `zaz` variable will be created every time the loop body is evaluated.

If, however, there is a `zaz` local variable in the surrounding scope, then `zaz` is a free variable in the block, and since block scopes nest in their surrounding scope, the existing `zaz` variable outside the block will be re-assigned over and over again, every time the block is evaluated.

You can ensure that `zaz` is always treated as a block-local variable and never looked up in the surrounding scope, by explicitly declaring it as a block-local variable in the block's parameter list:

```
foo.each do |bar; zaz|
  zaz = bar.first
end
```

Note, however, that your code only makes sense **IFF** your code is impure and mutable:

1. You assign to `zaz` but never actually use it inside the block. So, the only way that this makes sense at all is if `zaz` is a local variable in the outer scope and you are assigning it. Although in that case, your entire loop is just equivalent to `zaz = foo.last.first`.
2. `each` evaluates the block only for its side-effects. Without side-effects, `each` makes no sense at all, so the fact that you are using `each` implies that you have side-effects.

---

Note that the term "immutable" without additional qualification usually refers to values. When talking about "immutable variables", we usually say "immutable variable" explicitly, to make clear that we are only talking about whether or not a variable can be re-bound, not about mutating object state. Or, one could just say "constant", which is the technical term for "immutable variable" … although that term already has a specific meaning in Ruby.

Comment: I wouldn't say that "constant" is the technical term for "immutable variable". From the mathematical point of view at least, a constant is something that always has the same value (i.e. across multiple function applications etc.), like PI, which is always 3.14.... If I have something like `def f(x) y=x+1; y*y end` then both `x` and `y` are immutable - I never reassign them. But they're not constants in the mathematical sense because their values can be different each time `f` is applied. In the mathematical function `f(x) = y^2 where y=x+1`, `x` and `y` would be variables, not constants.